# Implementing Mean Squared Error for matrices in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am making a convolution autoencoder for images, and want to use MSE as the loss. Does an inbuilt function implementation of MSE exist for matrices?

Comment: tf.squared_difference(x, y, name=None)

Comment: @user2717954 Thanks. Shoulkd have looked deeper.

Comment: @user2717954 Just confirming, when py_x is what my NN feed-forward result image matrix is, and y is desired image matrix 
output,`cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(py_x, Y))` is the MSE per image or per pixel?

Comment: @user2717954 I just tried this with `py_x=[[8,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` and `Y=[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]` and got the answer `10`[(64/2)/3]. Assuming each of py_x[i] is a single image, and py_x[i][j] is pixel j of image i, doesn't this mean that the MSE reported is per pixel and not per image matrix?

Comment: @user2717954 sorry, that should have been `py_x=[[8,0],[0,0],[0,0]]` and `Y=[[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]]`

Comment: eventually you have 2 tensors you want to compute MSE on. what is the data represented by your tensors is under your complete control. All squared_difference does is calc (x-y)^2 element wise. I think I understand your problem now, reduce_mean will reduce the 2d tensor into 1 number. you need to specify the dimension if you don't won't all dimensions to be reduced

Comment: @user2717954 I was under the misconception(my own fault) that `tf.reduce_mean()` would only take the mean of the sum of the errors of the various batches(I am training in mini-batches) and hence the MSE produced would be per image, not per pixel. However, that does not seem to be the case and the error calculated is per pixel. The model's training happens in the right direction either way. It is just that assuming the error to be per image gave me wrong indications about the convergence of the network.

Comment: cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(py_x, Y), 1) will return per pixel, cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(py_x, Y), 0) will return per image

Comment: @user2717954 Got that part. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: you welcome, sorry for wasn't so clear initially